# whatsapp share includes html

Tags: android, html

I have this link which I am sharing through my app to whatsapp and its working fine but the problem is that it shares all html involve in the link,

```
       <a rel="nofollow" href="whatsapp://send?text=Agr facebook par job hoti<br />  ,<br />  ,<br />  ,<br />  ,<br />  ,<br />  ,<br />  ,<br />  ,<br />  ,<br />  ,<br />  ,<br />  ,<br />  ,<br />  ,<br />  ,<br />  ,<br />  ,<br />  ,<br />  ,<br />  to Maa kehti uth ja beta, facebook ka<br />  time ho gaya hai ...!!!!" data-action="share/whatsapp/share" ><span class="whatsapp">&nbsp;</span></a>
```

I can remove all html from text above but then formatting will not be good.

I tried urlenconde and rawurlencode but nothing is working.

Can anyone help?
My output should be like this when shared in whatsapp -

```
       Agr facebook par job hoti
,
,
,
  ,
   ,
  ,
  ,
  ,
    ,
     ,
   ,
   ,
   ,
     ,
      ,
    ,
      ,
   ,
    ,
 to Maa kehti uth ja beta, facebook ka
    time ho gaya hai ...!!!!
```

but when I share in whatsapp from my android app, it shares all html ,
 etc.

Comment: kindly share you java code :-)

Comment: @JNF can you show me what is coming as output?

Comment: @nigram, I only edited. Try tagging the OP